# php how to create an admin panel with Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, admin

I'm trying to create my admin panel in my website with Facebook.
So I'd like to view via PHP if the Facebook user id is mine or of a friend.
until i was just wondering only MY user id, all right. The admin panel functioned perfectly. But if in the "if" i add another id, nobody can view the admin panel neither me! **(so if the user logged-in is me OR my friend let us pass, else block it and exit with a message where explain that the user don't have necessary permissions to view the admin panel.)** 
How to do what i want to do?
Thanks

```
    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

if($user_id) {

  // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
  // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
  try {
    if (($user_id!="123456789") || ($user_id!="987654321"))
        exit("no permissions");
    else
    {
       // ...todo..
     }
   // etc... etc...
```

Comment: Simple logic error if the user id is 987654321 the 1st part of the check will fail, and vise versa.

Comment: mmh but i've used the OR not the AND. So if one is true is not necessary the that the last should be true

Comment: If user is NOT user 1 OR user is nNOT user2, then fail. User can never be both, so it always fails. IF you where checking for truthfull conditions, it would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, this is a simple logic error:
if the user id is 987654321 the 1st part of the check will fail, and vise versa.
A possible solution for you:

```
$admin_users=array('123456789', '987654321');
if(!in_array($user_id, $admin_users){
exit("no permissions");
else
{
   // ...todo..
 }
```